# Multi dispatching or nested dispatching

Tags: action, ngxs

I have store which has two fields:

- `items: Item[]`
- `money: number`

When user buys item **I call to apiService** and if the response from the server allows you to add an item (the server will check if the user has enough money) **I can make two changes in my store**:

1. push new item to array
2. decrease money

---

I am confused about what is good practise about dispatching actions...
**Which way is the best?**

1. Multi-dispatching - dispatch `AddItem` action and `DecreaseMoney` action:

```
store.dispatch([new AddItem(), new DecreaseMoney()]);
```

2. Subscribe `AddItem` action and dispatch `DecreaseMoney` action when first is successful:

```
this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(AddItem)).subscribe(() => {store.dispatch(new DecreaseMoney()});
```

3. Dispatch `DecreaseMoney` action inside `AddItem` action:

```
@Action(AddItemAction)
  AddItem({ getState, setState }: StateContext<any>) {
    const state = getState();
    return this.http.post(`${apiUrl}/buy`, {}).pipe(
      tap(newItem => {
        setState({...state, items: [...state.items, newItem]});
        dispatch(new DecreaseMoney()); // <---
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the actions do not mutate the same piece of state, I would recommend using multi-dispatching as it is less verbose.  If you depend on a returned response from your first async action, I think your nested setup is logical. However, it doesn't look like you pass in anything to DecreaseMoney()...so the first option seems best.

edit:

I would go with option 2 then as this could be a specific scenario. If you put all the logic in your action, you are coupling the DecreaseMoney() to AddItem(). By putting the business logic within your component/container, you can create reusable actions. That is what I would do, personally.

Comment: I don't pass anything to second action because I know how much money to reduce (from the json asset) but I'm not sure if the first action will succeed. To dispatch the second action I must be sure that the server allowed me to buy the item.

Comment: I would go with option 2 then as this could be a specific scenario.  If you put all the logic in your action, you are coupling the DecreaseMoney() to AddItem().  By putting the business logic within your component/container, you can create reusable actions. That is what I would do, personally.

Comment: Thanks for advice! :)

Comment: Not a problem :) please mark as best answer if you see fit.